# Three partitions after I dual booted ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

The first OS I had installed was Windows 7. I then dual booted ubuntu 15.04. After I go back into disk management in Windows 7, there shows 3 different partitions. My main windows 7, ubuntu, and a small partition. What was the small partition created for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The small partition (mine is 32 GB<sup>*</sup>, the same as my RAM) is called SWAP.

[image]

SWAP is a place for items currently in RAM but not being used to be moved to. It frees up space in the ram and helps prevent crashes.

It should be inside an extended partition - and my actual SWAP has `Contents Unknown`, but shows up as `Linux swap` (that's the reason for the dotted lines in GParted).

<sup>Actually, mine is 31.98 GiB - I guess because of conversion between 1024 MB in a GB and 1000 MB in a GB.</sup>

Comment: This is what Disk Management looks like on windows 7.

http://i.gyazo.com/755e4a0e7f2e197feaeb4c24efab415d.png

Why isn't my  SWAP partition in my extended partition. When I dual booted ubuntu onto my drive, I just shrinked my drive and gave it 45 GB. So now I have a 41.10 GB and a 3.90 GB partition. Did I dual boot wrong?

Comment: @qpp37 nope nothing wrong with that. That's how windows shows it.

Answer (score 0):

That's your SWAP partition it supplements your RAM.